# Which article do we use for countable units of uncountable things?

Tags: noun, gender, grammatical-number, countability

I have a question about the plural. There are countable nouns like

> die Banane, das Ei, die Birne, der Apfel

as well as uncountable nouns

> der Wein, der Champagner, das Salz

So when we put it in some container like Packung, Schachtel, Flasche, what article should be put before them?

For example:

> Flasche Champagner

Does the article here depend on the gender of the unit (die Flasche, feminine) or the thing it contains (der Champagner, masculine)?

Also, for some countable nouns, it is plural in some cases

> Dose Tomaten, zwei Dosen Tomaten

Also, I don't know why there are plural forms for uncountable nouns like Champagne, Sojasoße, Schokolade, can anybody explain this to me, sorry for such a stupid question.

Comment: Do you mean "der Champagner" (the bubbling wine) or "die Champagne" (the region)?

Comment: what plural nouns do you mean? I do not know anything about "Schokoladen"...

Comment: "for some countable nouns, it is plural in some cases" -> not for some, but for all of them.

Comment: The gender of the article is determined by the head noun, not the modifying one: *die Weinflasche*, *der Flaschenwein*. Think of *die Flasche Wein* as a particular kind of *Flasche*, with a postpositive modifier similar to *attorney general*.

Answer (score 13):

The article is always that of the container.

> Eine/Die Schachtel Salz
>
> Eine/Die Flasche Wein

The containers are countable, so if you've got multiple containers containing anything, the article is the plural form of the containers article

> Viele Flaschen Wein

If you want to point at a certain set of bottles containing wine, you would probably use the aggregate word **Weinflaschen** instead:

> Die Weinflaschen

This works exactly the same if the content is countable - all that counts (pun intended) is the gender of the container:

> Die Dose Tomaten

As to why many uncountable nouns still have plural forms:

They are used to indicate that there are multiple distinct kinds of this uncountable thing.

You could say something like

> Das Weingut ist bekannt für seine ausgezeichneten Rotweine.

meaning that it produced more than one kind of red whine.

Comment: The answer extends to units in the SI sense, e.g. "das Kilo Zucker" and "der Liter Milch".

Answer (score 4):

> I don't know why there are plural forms for uncountable nouns like
>   Champagner, Sojasoße, Schokolade

Because you can still talk about salts, waters, or the various brands of champagne or chocolate:

Ich mag Schokoladen mit hohem Kakaogehalt. Chemiker interessieren sich für die Salze der Schwefelsäure. In Deutschland werden vor allem halbtrockene Sekte (non-vintage champagnes) getrunken.

Comment: Wichtige Anmerkung, aber wohl eher ein Kommentar.

Comment: This answers the question posed in the last sentence. It is a (partial) answer.

Answer (score 1):

In almost all cases the German article for plural forms is "die".
For example:

> das Weinfass

plural:

> *die* Weinfässer

Combined nouns always use the article of the last part of the combination.

Another example was "chocolate":

singular:

> die Schokolade

countable form:

> die Schokoladentafel

plural of countable form:

> *die* Schokoladentafeln

derived from: Duden Bd. 4: Deutsche Grammatik

also I'm a native speaker

Comment: Wieso "almost all", welche Ausnahmen sind Dir denn bekannt?